# Connecting jhipster remotely to postgres

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, jdbc, jhipster

I'm trying to configure jhipster to work with heroku's postgres database. Here are my database parameters with credentials redacted:

```
spring:
    profiles: dev
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url:
        databaseName: xxxx
        serverName: ec2-54-225-182-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com
        username: xxxx
        password: xxxx
```

It results in this error that I determined is because I need to enable SSL:

```
[DEBUG] com.john_g_shultz.site.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Maximum connection creation retries exceeded: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "72.69.103.36", user "xxxxxx", database "xxxxxx", SSL off
```

According to heroku, remote database connections require JDBC connection URL with two SSL parameters. I have not been able to configure this URL successfully.

> Connecting to a database remotely
>
> If you’re using a Heroku Postgres database you can connect to it
>   remotely for maintenance and debugging purposes. However doing so
>   requires that you use an SSL connection. Your JDBC connection URL will
>   need to include the following:
>   ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to format the credentials for remote postgres connection

```
spring:
    profiles: dev
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://HOSTNAME/DATABASENAME?user=xxxx&password=xxxx&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
        databaseName:
        serverName:
        username: xxxx
        password: xxxx
```

Comment: Provide a SSLSocketFactory that allows SSL connections to be made without validating the server's certificate. This is more convenient for some applications, but is less secure as it allows "man in the middle" attacks... for anyone who is coming here like me!